# How to connect to remote system using telnet?

Tags: telnet

I am trying to connect to another windows system using telnet as follows:

```
   1.I open cmd.
   2.type "telnet"
   3.then type telnet "ip-address of remote system" e.g telnet 15.228.40.25.14
```

Now when I hit enter get error as:

```
 Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:connect failed
```

So, please suggest how do i resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the telnet connection as

```
telnet 192.168.10.10 3333
```

without using `:`

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct, but the other computer has to be running a telnet server for you to connect to it on port 23.